# Why i missing dependencies in aws lambda when deploy packages in python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-packaging

Trying in AWS Lambda Deploy Package using Python. Installed all imports in a folder where my python script. All imports working in Python but when uploading a .zip file to AWS Lambda and trying to run have an error that I missing some dependencies.

Error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqkCx.jpg Error showing what dependencies i missing

I have tried reinstall 'numpy' and 'pandas' inside folder and globally in python37-32/lib/site-packages... But didn't help

```py
import boto3
import os,sys
import base64
import binascii
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from ASNDEF import *
from pyasn1.codec.ber.decoder import decode as ber_decoder

def Decoder(event=None,context=None):
    return {'hello':'123'}
```

Expect upload python package in AWS Lambda and run it without missing dependencies

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but if I need to use a library that is not available in lambda environment I create a layer with that library and then reference that layer in my lambda. Also, make sure that your libraries are in `python` folder as that's how lambda envronment works, check out this blog for more details: https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some issue when you try to upload the latest version of numpy with the deployment package to a lambda function.

I used this git link - https://github.com/pbegle/aws-lambda-py3.6-pandas-numpy/blob/master/lambda.zip to download the numpy, pandas library and zipped it along with the other required python libraries and my lambda_function.py file and it worked for me.

Note: The size limit for extracted version of the deployment package is 250 MB as of now

Comment: My ass is blazing, tried this approach https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e and it's working for "pandas and  numpy" but after this not working pyarrow dependencies which depend on pandas and numpy, after that tried unzip all my imports as linux libraries after it not working new dependency, fix it that dependency not working other dependency fixed that and came to the same error i tried to fix, tried your approach too not working for me(

Comment: @DOIT Can you please show the error which is thrown and list all the libraries you need to use?

Comment: These libraries I need to use (pandas pyarrow  pyasn1 asn1ate). Can't make them work together in lambda but works on pc

Comment: No module named 'pyarrow.lib' after i fixed 'numpy' dependency

Comment: @SerhiiZ Did you fix this issue of pyarrow.lib?